# How to Run two OS simultaneously on one Laptop

Tags: windows, sandbox

There is a program I must run which takes up the entire OS and will shut off if the application is closed or minimized to another program, so I was wondering if there is a way to make the program think it is taking over the entire OS while I run Chrome in another OS. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean "takes up the entire OS"? "There is a program I must run"... Which program are you referring to?

Comment: There is a program called lockdown browser which is designed to ensure external applications are not being used and does not allow the use of other applications while it is running. I am looking for a way to get around this. Thank you!

Comment: @annmordeh Remove the program in question.  You will need to be an Administrator for this to be possible

Comment: I cannot remove the program. I think there is a misunderstanding because I need to run this application in addition to another one, but LockDown does not permit the use of other applications while in use. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want to cheat at an exam? Anyway, you could try VirtualBox.

Comment: Lmao you know it

Comment: I will definitely check it out. Thank you so much @SpiderPig

Comment: There are also other ways to get around LockDown. For example by using [a tool that causes chrome windows to always be on top](https://www.howtogeek.com/196958/the-3-best-ways-to-make-a-window-always-on-top-on-windows/) or doing something more sophisticated like [this](http://pepijndevos.nl/2016/07/10/breaking-the-respondus-lockdown-browser.html).

Comment: Dang you are an expert

Comment: Yeah, an expert in using google

Comment: Yo. For that link do you know how to run that code. I have no idea how to use it :(

Comment: Which code? The java code in the second link? Yes, I know how to run it but you need a Wolfram Alpha account for that. To run it without an account you'd need to change the code quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a powerful enough machine and admin rights what you could do is visualize the OS so it runs that os only. Since the browser locks the OS down you'll have to virtualize the lockdown browser application. Please note that you'll have to install the OS in the virtual machine before installing the application, but its doable. There are a couple of free virtualization software that you can use. Here are a few free solutions.

Oracle Virtualbox
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

VMware player
http://www.vmware.com/products/player/playerpro-evaluation.html

Note: If you are trying to virtualize windows you might have to buy an OS license, depending on your budget it could prove to be expensive.

Comment: Okay, I really hope this doesn't sound dumb. While trying to download virtualbox it says I haven't adjusted my settings and cannot install it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried opening the installer as administrator? Is that the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Yup still no luck. Even as admin. It is saying my system is not modified

Comment: TBH, never encountered the error before. But after some reading around, it seems that it has to do with the fact that your windows might be out of date. It seems that the error pops out if windows can not find the certificate. Updating windows might solve the issue. It solved it for this guy [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549049/virtualbox-5-0-install-error-your-system-has-not-been-modified)

Comment: If you are running Win 10, check this setting: https://www.howtogeek.com/302352/how-to-allow-only-apps-from-the-store-on-windows-10-and-whitelist-desktop-apps/